# What mistake I'm making while adding a new trigger on a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, constraints

Following is the trigger I've written :

```
CREATE TRIGGER `test_BINS` BEFORE INSERT ON `phpfox_user` FOR EACH ROW 
IF new.`full_name` = '' THEN SET new.`full_name` = NULL; END IF; END;
```

Following is the screen shot of the same:
[image: The New Trigger I written]

Following is the image of error message that came :

[image: Error while adding the new trigger]

Please somebody help me in adding this trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER test_BINS BEFORE INSERT ON phpfox_user
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
      IF (NEW.full_name = '') THEN
            SET NEW.full_name = NULL;
      END IF;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

but if you want to add it using pma-interface, just place there this definition:

```
BEGIN
      IF (NEW.full_name = '') THEN
            SET NEW.full_name = NULL;
      END IF;
END
```

Comment: If(NEW.full_name = '') then I want to use the value from the field 'user_name' of the same record instead of NULL. How should I do it?

Comment: alot of  questions in one? :)

Comment: BEGIN
      IF (NEW.full_name = '') THEN
            SET NEW.full_name = NEW.user_name;
      END IF;
END

Answer (score 0):

The message is clear here. Whatever is present in the line 1 of your first image is not needed, as the information is already provided above.

Technically, your code tries to create a trigger inside another trigger. Remove the line 1 and it will be fine.

This should be the query:

```
FOR EACH ROW IF :new.full_name = '' THEN :new.full_name := NULL; END IF; END;
```

Comment: Still I'm getting the error. Tell me what is 'new' standing for?

Comment: @PHPLover new stands for the row values after updation. new.full_name will be the name in  that record, after that sql is performed

Comment: Following error I received : 
MySQL said : #1064- You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL version for the right syntax to use near 'FOR EACH ROW IF new.`full_name` = '' THEN SET new.`full_name` = NULL; EN' at line 1

Comment: One more doubt I have instead of using 'new' can I use data from some other field of the same record? If yes how? If no why?

Comment: @PHPLover: you can use new.anyColumn .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88475/discussion-between-phplover-and-aswin-murugesh).